# parse json data with serde_json and print out all the keys

Tags: json, rust

This is a simple example for rust to parse json data. Now after parsing how do I find out the keys of a `serde_json::Value`, e.g. `"name", "age", "phones"` in the example?

```rust
fn json_hello_world() {
    // Some JSON input data as a &str. Maybe this comes from the user.
    let data = r#"
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "age": 43,
            "phones": [
                "+44 1234567",
                "+44 2345678"
            ]
        }"#;

    // Parse the string of data into serde_json::Value.
    let value: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();

    println!(
        "Please call {} at the number {}",
        value["name"], value["phones"][0]
    );


    /*
    // how do I print out the keys?
    for key in value.keys() {
        println!("{}", key);
    }
    */
}

fn main() {
    json_hello_world();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `value` is an object (and not an array or something different), you can use [`as_object`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/enum.Value.html#method.as_object):

```rust
for key in value.as_object().unwrap().keys() {
    println!("{}", key);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=254c6109ae34f22ce14b01b2b18dda53)